# on updating any field from dropdown list into MYSQL with white space, data gets truncated

Tags: php

I'm working on PHP and MySQL. inserting data and even retriving them are all fine. when i insert any data from dropdown list works fine and i can see data correctly inserted. if i dont change any data in the dropdown list and simply click on update button then those data having white space or / get truncated. for example:  red rose or red / rose  after clicking on update button becomes red. this is only happens when i try to update from dropdown list otherwise from text-box or text-area i have no problem even if i use apastrophe or / or white space.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it looks to me like you're ommitting quotes. Maybe you have something like:

```
<option value=red rose>
```

This won't work; you need to quote the value to look like this:

```
<option value="red rose">
```

In your PHP code perhaps:

```
<option value=<?= $variable ?>>
```

Change to:

```
<option value="<?= $variable ?>">
```

Feel free to post some concrete code and we'll be happy to go over it and help you fix it.